# I follow phpfox guide but My plugin now show?

Tags: php, phpfox

I build a phpfox in my local (win10 - xampp v3.2.1). It work fine.
But when i trying to create some codes folow [phpfox guide](https://store.phpfox.com/kb/article/144/creating-your-first-add-on)
line "Creating a Plugin from a PHP File". But when I view my profile/info/, there are not anything I wrote in plugin show here. Any one know about this problem, pls explain to me, thank

Comment: Sorry for all, after I send my question, my modifier already show in profile page. Cause is cache, although I set "define('PHPFOX_NO_TEMPLATE_CACHE', true); define('PHPFOX_NO_CSS_CACHE', true);" in debug.sett.php.